# Can a empty string be passed in the url in django?

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django project which have a posts page. I have its url as follows:

```
path('posts/<str:sort>', views.posts, name='posts'),
```

and this is what its view looks like:

```
def posts(request,sort)
    b=""
    if b=="time":
        posts=Post.objects.all().order_by(b)
    else:
        posts=Post.objects.all()
    return render(request,posts.html,{'posts':posts})
```

Now what I want is that if there is nothing passed as sort in the url or the url is like : /posts/ I want to display all posts but if the parameter is 'time' then I want to order_by as in my view. But currently if nothing is passed in url for sort then I get the error that no path found the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str` converter is defined as follows:

```
class StringConverter:
    regex = '[^/]+'
    
    # other methods
```

Which means it requires at least one character (note `+`, not `*`). You can create a new url mapping and manually pass empty string as `sort` parameter:

```
path('posts/', views.posts, kwargs={'sort': ''})
```

You can also [register your own converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) to allow empty string or just switch to plain old [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path). These options are preferred in case if you want to reduce code repetition and reuse this behavior somewhere else. They also allow you to keep the same url name (useful if you're planning to `reverse` urls)

Comment: So that means I can have two paths for the same view? Also on passing empty sort how do I handle it in view?Can I do smthing like `if sort==" ": statement`

Comment: Yes, you can have as many paths for the same view as you like. To handle sort parameter just change `b=="time"` to `sort == 'time'` - this will be enough for your case

Comment: Ok but what when I am sort is empty as you told in a path. Can I do `if sort==" ": statement`

Comment: No, you cannot compare to string with space (unless your path will actually include a space), you either need to compare with empty string or just `if not sort:`